# R: dplyr: How can I refer to columns in arrange() without knowing their name?

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr is a great package that I try to use consistently in my code.
It produces very readable code.

The select(3,4) function allows me to select third and fourth column.

I would like to use the same method in the arrange() method. 
In SQL going by numbers or names works interchangeably. (which is great)

Unfortunately, I have to use only names with dplyr::arrange()

Is there a code pattern I can use if I know I will need to order (arrange) by 3rd column. In my code, the name of that column will change but I will always need order by 3rd column. (position will not)

See the problem here:

```
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
> library(sqldf)
> sqldf('select * from mtcars order by 2,3 limit 10')
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
2  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
3  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
4  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
5  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
6  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
7  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
8  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
9  21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
10 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
> #arrange(mtcars,cyl,disp)
> #this works but I have to use names to refer to the columns :-(
```

Sometning like arrange(mtcars,3) . For example, arrange(mtcars,names(mtcars)[3]) does not work. :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `arrange_`

```
arrange_(mtcars, names(mtcars)[3])
```

Comment: This solves it. Thanks you. Any comments on why _ function works. I wish the dplyr official help would hint to how they differ. Or some dplyr tutorial explaining the _ functions

Comment: [Here's the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) explaining the _

Answer (score 2):

Updating for dplyr 1.0:

```
arrange(mtcars, across(names(mtcars)[3]))
```